# How can I use error handling when reading xlsx files in R?

Tags: r, excel

I am trying to read 23 excel files, store each in a list, and then rbind them to one csv. Some of these file are csv and some of them are xlsx. However, I got the following message:

```
Error: Can't establish that the input is either xls or xlsx.
```

So I want to identify which ones are giving error and then append it manually.

My function is the following:

```
make_df<-function(filename){
  library(readxl)
  library(foreign)
  if (str_sub(filename,-3,-1) == "csv"){
    df<-read.csv(filename,fileEncoding="latin1")
  }
    else{
      df<-read_excel(filename)
    }
  return(df)
}

filenames_vector<-list.files(# directory)


datalist = list()

for (i in 1:23){
  datalist[[i]] <- make_df(filenames_vector[i])
}


mega_data = do.call(rbind,datalist)
```

How can I add something in make_df to print out the names of files that are causing the error message? Also, is there another work around, when the the error message is on not being able to distinguish xlsx from xls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with a tryCatch block. Without example data it's a little hard to recreate. I'm not sure what you mean in your second question.

Try the code below to catch errors and print out the filename if there's an error, otherwise return the df object.

```
make_df<-function(filename){
  library(readxl)
  library(foreign)

  df = tryCatch(
   { # try block
     if (str_sub(filename,-3,-1) == "csv"){
       df<-read.csv(filename,fileEncoding="latin1")
     }
     else{
       df<-read_excel(filename)
     }
   },
   error=function(cond){return(filename)} # grab the filename if there was an error
  )

  if (class(df) == 'character') {
    print(df)
  } else{return(df)}

}
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try this. The second Q was just asking if there are other ways to solve the error message because I'm not sure what is causing the problem.